# How to prove the sum of 2 Gaussian distribution is also a Gaussian distribution using the characteristic function

Tags: statistics, characteristic-functions, gaussian

Let X and Y be two $ \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $ distributions. I have to prove that for $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2 $, $ aX + bY $ is equal to $\mathcal{N}(0, a^2 + b^2)$.

I'm trying to do this using the characteristic function of a Gaussian distribution.
$$ \phi_{aX + bY}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{ \mathbb{e}^{it(ax+by)}{\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}} dx} $$

I don't really know what to do since by changing the variable I can't replace both x and y. Any sugestions ?

Comment: You would need to use the joint PDF of $X,Y$. If they are independent variables, you may see that $\phi_{aX+bY}(t)=\phi_{aX}(t)\cdot\phi_{bY}(t)=\exp\left(\frac t2(a^2+b^2)\right)$ which gives us the desired result.

Comment: This is not true unless you assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri small typo with $^2$ missing, so $\exp\left(\frac {t^2}2(a^2+b^2)\right)$

Comment: @Henry Noted. Can't fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z=aX+bY$. The characteristic function of $Z$ is:

$\phi_Z(t)=E\{e^{itZ}\}=E\{e^{it(aX+bY)}\}=E\{e^{i(at)X}e^{i(bt)Y)}\}$

**EDIT** (Sloppy mistake...) *If* X and Y are independent:

$\phi_Z(t)=E\{e^{i(at)X}\}E\{e^{i(bt)Y)}\}=\phi (at) \phi (bt)$,

where $\phi(w)=e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}}$ is the characteristic function of the normal distribution. So,

$\phi_Z(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}(at)^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(bt)^2}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)t^2}$,

which is the characteristic function of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: "Since" should be "if", as independence hasn't been specified.

Comment: You are right. I didn't pay attention. My answer is ultimately wrong.